# Get related fields from MAX() query

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to write a subquery that will select the highest price as well as the item name associated with that highest price.

For example:

```
ID | Price | Item Name
1 | 28.99 | Lamp
2 | 13.99 | USB Cable
```

I am expecting to get "28.99" and "Lamp" with my sub-query.  The main query looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    i.id
FROM
    inventory i
```

My sub-query within the main query looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    (SELECT MAX(pl.price) FROM price_list pl WHERE pl.id = i.id) AS highest,
    (SELECT MAX(pl.item_name) FROM price_list pl WHERE pl.id = i.id) AS highestName
FROM
    inventory i
```

However, using MAX() on an item name is going to return the highest ranked alphabetical name, which is not what I want.  I want to get the item name associated with the highest price.  What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What SQL engine are you using? The answers given so far are good but not the best option when you have multiple "top" results

Answer (score 2):

You coudl use a subquery for match the where

```
  select price as  highest , item_name  highestName
  from price  
  where price = (
    select max(Price)
    from price_list
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a query like this:

```
SELECT Price, Name
FROM price_list
WHERE Price = (SELECT MAX(PL.Price) FROM price_list PL)
```